# Does the chance of getting your transaction confirmed increase with faster CPU?

Tags: transaction, pending, pow

It can be painfully difficult to get a transaction confirmed, so I've found various suggestions to improve this, as:

- choose a well synched full node
- choose a full node with low ping time
- use promote button (why the wallet can't do this on its own is another question)

However, I suspect one key factor affecting confirmation probability is pure CPU power to do PoW. I'm using an old low-power PC, so not much in terms of PoW power.

Is it true that the longer my PoW takes after selecting the tips, the more the tangle will have moved on when I'm finished, the less attractive is my new tip to others, the less likely it is that I will EVER get a confirmation on my transaction?

Comment: I actually just got my bundle through with a much faster PC, reattaching and then promoting 6x5times in a row, so I just hit promote again after 5 promotes were done. So: at least worth a try, if you experience ever-pending transactions and nothing else helps.

Answer (score 4):

If the POW last for a long time, your transaction will be attached to relatively old transactions when it will be broadcasted to the network. It will looks like a "lazy tip".

"Lazy tip" have less chance to be selected by the random walk, so yes a fast CPU/GPU increase your chance to see your transaction confirmed.